# Visual Studio cannot find my methods despite them being spelled correctly

Tags: visual-studio, c++11

I'm getting many unresolved symbol errors, and I can't figure out why.

The most common sources of this issue seem to be misspelled method names, forgetting to indicate what class the methods belong to using the scoping operator, and forgetting to include the `.cpp` file in the project.

I've checked all of these issues though, and none of them seem to apply. I'm telling it what class the methods belong to (via `Point<T>:: ...`), I've double checked the method names, and they're all correct, and the `.cpp` file is shown in the Solution Explorer (I even tried removing it and re-adding it).

I haven't written C++ in awhile, so I may be overlooking something, but I can't see what.

(After posting this, I realized my operators are comically broken. That shouldn't effect my error though, so please ignore for the time being).

Specifically, these are the errors I'm getting:

```
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Point<int>::Point<int>(int,int)" (??0?$Point@H@@QAE@HH@Z) referenced in function _main
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class Point<int> __thiscall Point<int>::operator+(class Point<int>)const " (??H?$Point@H@@QBE?AV0@V0@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class Point<int> __thiscall Point<int>::operator-(class Point<int>)const " (??G?$Point@H@@QBE?AV0@V0@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class Point<int> __thiscall Point<int>::operator*(class Point<int>)const " (??D?$Point@H@@QBE?AV0@V0@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class Point<int> __thiscall Point<int>::operator/(class Point<int>)const " (??K?$Point@H@@QBE?AV0@V0@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class Point<int>)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@V?$Point@H@@@Z) referenced in function _main
```

And these are the files in question:

Point.h

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Point {
    const T x;
    const T y;

public:
    Point(T x, T y);

    Point<T> moveBy(T xOff, T yOff) const;

    Point<T> operator+(const Point<T> otherPoint) const;
    Point<T> operator-(const Point<T> otherPoint) const;
    Point<T> operator*(const Point<T> otherPoint) const;
    Point<T> operator/(const Point<T> otherPoint) const;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point<T> p);

private:
    Point<T> applyOperator(T(*f)(T, T), const Point<T> otherPoint) const;
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point<T> p) {
    return os << "(" << p.x << "," << p.y << ")";
}

#endif
```

Point.cpp:

```
#include "Point.h"

template <typename T>
Point<T>::Point(T x, T y) :
    x(x),
    y(y) {

}

template <typename T>
Point<T> Point<T>::moveBy(T xOff, T yOff) const {
    return this + Point(xOff, yOff);
}

template <typename T>
Point<T> Point<T>::operator+(const Point<T> otherPoint) const {
    return applyOperator([](x, y) {x + y});
}

template <typename T>
Point<T> Point<T>::operator-(const Point<T> otherPoint) const {
    return applyOperator([](x, y) {x - y});
}

template <typename T>
Point<T> Point<T>::operator*(const Point<T> otherPoint) const {
    return applyOperator([](x, y) {x * y});
}

template <typename T>
Point<T> Point<T>::operator/(const Point<T> otherPoint) const {
    return applyOperator([](x, y) {x / y});
}

template <typename T>
Point<T> Point<T>::applyOperator(T(*f)(T, T), const Point<T> otherPoint) const {
    return Point(f(this.x, otherPoint.x), f(this.y, otherPoint.y));
}
```

And the Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Point.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Point<int> p1(1, 2);
    Point<int> p2(2, 3);

    std::cout << p1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << p2 << std::endl;

    Point<int> p3 = p1 + p2;
    Point<int> p4 = p1 - p2;
    Point<int> p5 = p1 * p2;
    Point<int> p6 = p1 / p2;

    std::cout << p3 << std::endl;
    std::cout << p4 << std::endl;
    std::cout << p5 << std::endl;
    std::cout << p6 << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the class template member function definitions are in `Point.cpp`, but when this file is compiled the compiler doesn't know that the template needs to be instantiated for `T` = `int`.  In fact, I imagine `Point.obj` is essentially empty.

The compiler happily compiles `Main.cpp` with its calls to `Point<int>`'s members - expecting them to be provided at link time - but the linker then complains because it can't find those members defined anywhere.

The solution is to either (a) move Point's member function definitions into `Point.hpp`, or (b) force the instantiation of `Point<int>` in `Point.cpp` by explicitly declaring that specialisation:  simply add the line `template class Point<int>;` at the end of `Point.cpp`.

Comment: WOW. I can't believe I forgot about that! Thank you very much.